# cloudconfig | Windows Server | run powershell script as Admin

Tags: windows, powershell, cloud-init

Do you know how I should add a server into a domain using cloud config?

The following does not work from cloud config when deploying new VM but within the Windows Server VM is working fine!.

```
cloudConfig: |
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==NewPart"
MIME-Version: 1.0


--==NewPart
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-init.ps1"

#ps1_sysnative 
Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "C:\Temp\domainjoin.ps1"
```

powershell Version: 5.1.14

```
 - path: C:\Temp\domainjoin.ps1
        content: |
          $domain = '${input.domain}'
          $username = '${input.username}' 
          $password = '${input.passwd}' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
          $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
          Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $cred -Force
        permissions: '0645'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
 cloudConfig: |
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==NewPart"
    MIME-Version: 1.0

--==NewPart
    Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config"

 - path: C:\Temp\domainjoin.ps1
        content: |
          $domain = '${input.domain}'
          $username = "mydomain\DomainUser"
          $password = "xxxxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
          $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
          Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $cred -Force
        permissions: '0645'  


--==NewPart
    Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config"


#ps1_sysnative
 Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -ArgumentList "C:\Temp\domainjoin.ps1" -Wait
  Sleep 5
  Restart-Computer -Force -Wait
```

Note:

- You can use this script to add your Windows Server into your domain
  via CloudConfig
- (-Wait) powershell is waiting for the script to execute before goes to the next line.